# Misunderstanding Einstein notation

Tags: vectors, tensors, vector-fields, tensor-rank, einstein-notation

I have an expression $$p_m p_j (\delta_{ij} r_m + \delta_{jm} r_i + \delta_{im} r_j)$$

So if we expand things out $$=(\delta_{ij} r_m p_m p_j+ \delta_{jm} r_i p_m p_j+ \delta_{im} r_j p_m p_j)$$

Evaluating the $\delta$'s we are left with

$$=r_m p_m p_i + r_i p_j p_j + r_j p_i p_j$$

Which would be (I think)

$$=(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{p})\vec{p} + \vec{r}(\vec{p} \cdot \vec{p}) + \vec{p}(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{p})$$
Which is fine. However, I want to divide the original expression through by $p_j$, leaving

$$p_m (\delta_{ij} r_m + \delta_{jm} r_i + \delta_{im} r_j) $$
Again expanding
$$=(\delta_{ij} r_m p_m + \delta_{jm} r_i p_m + \delta_{im} r_j p_m ) $$
$$=(\delta_{ij} r_m p_m + r_i p_j + r_j r_i)$$
Im not sure how to evaluate the delta in the final expression. Online sources I can find say $\delta_{ij}r_m p_m = r_i p_i$? Wouldn't this mean we're adding a tensor and scalar in the final expression? I'm confused.

Comment: $\delta_{ij} r_m p_m=\delta_{ij}(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{p})$, as you have to sum only over the $m$, which appears twice. In your final equation you sum three tensors.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense, thanks! So how would I write that in non-component form? Can the delta_{ij} be written as an identity matrix or something?

Comment: Exactly, $\delta_{ij}$ is the identity matrix, which is then multiplied by the scalar $(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{p})$.